# Handle select all checkboxes - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

Hey guys i am trying to assign a fucntion on my chechbox select all button to flip the state when button is clicked but i am doing something wrong . Can somebody help me ?

My state :

```
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           allCheckboxes: false
        };

 handleAllCheckboxes = (e) => {
    const allCheckboxesChecked = e.target.checked
    let checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkbox')
    this.setState({

        allCheckboxes: allCheckboxesChecked
    })
    console.log(allCheckboxesChecked)
```

My single checkbox :

```
      <Checkbox
            checked={this.handleAllCheckboxes ? true : false}
            name='checkbox'
            color='default'
            value={JSON.stringify({ documentId: rowData.documentId, documentNumber: rowData.documentNumber })}
            onClick={this.handleCheckboxClick}
                                    />
```

My select all checkbox:

```
      <Checkbox
           onChange={this.handleAllCheckboxes}
           indeterminate
           />Select All
```

The problem is that no matter what i do the state stay the same . It doesnt flip to true or false .

**UPDATE**

[image]

**UPDATE**

https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-khorana-j8mr6

Comment: how do you keep state for each checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

Hi Your Checkbox handler should lie out of constructor.

like below:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           allCheckboxes: true
        };
}




handleAllCheckboxes = (e) => {
    const allCheckboxesChecked = e.target.checked
    let checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkbox')
    this.setState({

        allCheckboxes: allCheckboxesChecked
    })
    console.log(allCheckboxesChecked)

}
```

and you have written **checked={this.handleAllCheckboxes ? true : false}** which looks wrong.Because **this.handleAllCheckboxes is already defined and therefore it will always return true.( Because function is always available.) **. Secondly handleAllCheckboxes is also not returning any true/false.

Comment: Hey @Pramod Nikam by this way i recieve always a truthy value

Comment: looks like this.handleAllCheckboxes ? true : false is a problem

Comment: `checked={this.state.allCheckboxese}` i flip it to return the answer from the state , but still the answer from the console is truthy .

Comment: Do check spelling also

Comment: What is out of  console.log(allCheckboxesChecked)?

Comment: I have updated my question you can see the response from the console

Comment: first of all is your handleAllCheckboxes = (e) => { function getting called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202870/discussion-between-pandamastr-and-pramod-nikam).

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep your checkboxes state in state, when clicking select all change their state to true and vise versa.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>


<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      checkBoxes: {
        vehicle1: false,
        vehicle2: false,
        vehicle3: false,
      }
    };
  }

  handleCheckBoxes = (checkBox, checkAll = false) => {

    if (checkAll) {

      const checkBoxes = { ...this.state.checkBoxes };

      Object.keys(checkBoxes).forEach((key) => {
        checkBoxes[key] = checkBox.target.checked;
      });

      this.setState({
        checkBoxes: checkBoxes
      })

      return;
    }

    const { checked, name } = checkBox.target;

    this.setState(
      prevState => {
        return {
          checkBoxes: { ...prevState.checkBoxes, [name]: checked }
        };
      },
      () => console.log(this.state)
    );

    // console.log(checkBox.target.checked);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={e => this.handleCheckBoxes(e, true)}
            name="vehicle1"
            value="Bike"
          />
          Select All
        </label>
        <br />
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={this.handleCheckBoxes}
          name="vehicle1"
          value="Bike"
          checked={this.state.checkBoxes["vehicle1"]}
        />
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={this.handleCheckBoxes}
          name="vehicle2"
          value="Car"
          checked={this.state.checkBoxes["vehicle2"]}
        />
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={this.handleCheckBoxes}
          name="vehicle3"
          value="Boat"
          checked={this.state.checkBoxes["vehicle3"]}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a package [grouped-checkboxes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@createnl/grouped-checkboxes) which can solve this problem.

You can simply wrap the checkboxes in a CheckboxGroup and add an AllChecker.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  CheckboxGroup,
  AllCheckerCheckbox,
  Checkbox
} from "@createnl/grouped-checkboxes";

const App = (props) => {
  const { products } = props

  return (
    <CheckboxGroup onChange={console.log}>
      <label>
        <AllCheckerCheckbox />
        Select all
      </label>
      {options.map(option => (
        <label>
          <Checkbox id={option.id} />
          {option.label}
        </label>
      ))}
    </CheckboxGroup>
  )
}
```

More examples see https://codesandbox.io/s/grouped-checkboxes-v5sww